# Admob load error: No ad config, even with test ad ids

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-admob

I'm trying to test out my ads implementation and for that I'm using test ad ids provided by google but getting no ad config Error.

```
App open ad load failed 3,No ad config.,{"Response ID": "null",
"Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",      
"Adapter Responses": [],       
"Response Extras": {}     
}
```

The above error result is just for app open but it's coming same for Interstitial ad also.

Test ID's I'm using are:
`app open: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294 interstitial: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 app id: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 //test app id also from google`

What's the issue here? What does it mean by no ad config when I'm using test ad ids?
PS: I also added test device id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was with the package ID, I changed the package ID and test ads started loading.

Comment: What means package id?